# Assembly: Write into a character array passed as a parameter from C++

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

I am writing an assembly function callable from C++ that will read the CPU Vendor ID. Here is the function signature:

```
extern "C" void GetVendorID(const char* id);
```

Here is how I am calling it:

```
char vendorID[13];
GetVendorID(vendorID);
vendorID[12] = '\0';
```

Here is the important parts of the assembly:

```
global GetVendorID
GetVendorID:

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    push eax
    push ebx
    push ecx
    push edx

    mov eax, 0
    cpuid ; <- this instruction moves the vendor id into ebx, edx, ecx

    mov eax, [ebp + 8] ; <- move the value of the char pointer parameter into eax
    ; I have verified that this instruction works by returning eax and comparing it to the
    ; address of the vendorID array

    ; start with ebx
    mov byte [eax], bl ; <- move a character into the char array
    inc eax ; <- increment the pointer
    shl ebx, 8 ; <- shift ebx to get the next character in its least significant bits
    mov byte [eax], bl ; <- repeat
    inc eax
    shl ebx, 8
    mov byte [eax], bl
    inc eax
    shl ebx, 8
    mov byte [eax], bl
    inc eax
    shl ebx, 8

    ; above is repeated for edx and ecx
    
    pop edx
    pop ecx
    pop ebx
    pop eax

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

The way the string is stored in the registers is weird. The first character is stored in the least significant byte of ebx, the next is stored in the second least significant byte, and so on. That is why I am doing the left shifts.

I have verified that ebx, edx, ecx do contain the correct values by returning them from the function and printing them out. They contain "GenuineIntel". However, the char array remains unchanged. It is full of zeroes after the function returns.

I am not really sure why this isn't working. Am I accessing the parameter incorrectly?

Comment: Since x86 is little endian, you don't need to shift. You can just do `mov [eax], ebx` and you will get the correct order. Note that `shl` is a left shift, if anything, you wanted a right shift. You should have gotten the first letter correctly though. Also, only `ebx` is callee saved, you don't need to push/pop the others. But that's not an error of course.

Comment: It is also weird to see you passing `const char*` pointer to function modifying it. I am also surprised that your way of accessing parameter works, what's your target platform?

Comment: Haha oops don't know why I put the const on there. Also thanks for the advice. It must have been because of little endian. I replaced the bl's with ebx and replaced the shl with shr and it works now. I am writing an operating system, so the platform I have the compiler and linker settings for is something like elf_i386

Comment: You either use `ebx` in which case you don't need shifts at all (recommended) **or** you use `shr` but then keep using `bl`. Don't do both. It's literally as simple as `mov [eax], ebx; mov [eax+4], edx; mov [eax+8], ecx`.

Comment: Yep just figured that out. Just replaced like 40 lines with 3 lol